# Vim switching between highlighted and non-highlighted syntax

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Here is my problem :

1. I open a file with `vim /etc/file.toml`, it's syntax-highlighted
2. I edit it and save it
3. Sometimes (not everytimes), when I re-open the file later, it's not syntax-highlighted anymore.

Anybody has an idea of how to fix this issue ? Cache problem ?

Note : that this problem occurs with almost every file extension, I do not switch user (always root).

Comment: We'd need to inspect your `.vimrc` and list of used plugins to help. Does `:syntax on` restore things?

Comment: I use the default .vimrc (I just added `set bg=dark`). `:syntax on` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are there still colors in `:hi` output? Does `:colorscheme default` restore things?

Comment: Yes, there are colors in `:hi`, `:colorscheme default`does nothing...

Comment: Do you have environment variable related to vim? `env | grep VIM`

Comment: Check the following values before and after the problem: `:verbose setlocal filetype? syntax?`; if one of them gets cleared / changed, that's the cause.

Comment: Also check your .bashrc, bash_profile etc. for VIM related env var.

Comment: Do you use the same term and env ?

Comment: There is no environment variable set anywhere. I don't know if what you've specified (Ingo Karkat) changed. And I can't verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `syntax enable` instead of `syntax on` in your .vimrc.

Straight from `:h syntax`

```
This command switches on syntax highlighting: >

    :syntax enable

What this command actually does is to execute the command >
    :source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim

If the VIM environment variable is not set, Vim will try to find
the path in another way (see |$VIMRUNTIME|).  Usually this works just
fine.  If it doesn't, try setting the VIM environment variable to the
directory where the Vim stuff is located.  For example, if your syntax files
are in the "/usr/vim/vim50/syntax" directory, set $VIMRUNTIME to
"/usr/vim/vim50".  You must do this in the shell, before starting Vim.

                            *:syn-on* *:syntax-on*
The ":syntax enable" command will keep your current color settings.  This
allows using ":highlight" commands to set your preferred colors before or
after using this command.  If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the
defaults, use: >
    :syntax on
```

Read [Here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading) for more info.

EDIT: After some more research, I've found that if the above doesn't work, it's because the filetype plugin for that specific filetype is overwriting the user settings. To combat this, you can create a new folder named `after` in your home vim folder. Each file in `after` is sourced after any files in `/usr/share/vim74`. The structure of `after` must match the structure of the vim74 folder folder.

To make things easier I wrote a quick script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Make the after folders you need
mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin

# Create the Global Settings file for syntax highlighting and formatting options
touch $HOME/.vim/after/fo_globals.vim

# Create links to the fo_globals file
for file in /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/*.vim
    do
        ln -s $HOME/.vim/after/fo_globals.vim $HOME/.vim/after/ftplugin/`basename $file`
    done
```

Then fill out your globals file with syntax and formatting options. Mine looks like this.

```
syntax enable
set formatoptions-=c
set formatoptions-=r
set formatoptions-=o
set autoindent
set smartindent
set nocindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start

set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
```

Comment: I'll try it soon but actually I can't access my VM. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: There is no change with the tips you gave me

Comment: Hmm. I remember having the exact same issue not too long ago, but unfortunately I can't seem to remember exactly what I did to fix it. Could I see your .vimrc. Also, the next time this issue happens, run `:5verbose set filetype?` and run `:5verbose set syntax?` and let me know what it says. I'll see if I can't remember what I changed in my vimrc that solved the issue.

Comment: The two commands gave me back this :  `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim` `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim`

Comment: The two commands return this :  `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim` `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim` (when the syntax highlighting is on, it just reappears this morning). When there is no highlighting, the commands return `filetype=` and `syntax=` (it diseappears again two minutes ago).

Comment: Ok, disregard that last comment, I finally found the solution. I'll edit my above answer, but I've tested it on a new install of vim where I was having the same exact issue, and everything works great.